# jqplot not displaying in knockout code

Tags: knockout.js, jqplot

I was following an knockout.js tutorial and everything works as expected except the chart is not being populated when a value is submitted in the input for weight or ounces. The chart data is pushed into the array, Im not sure what is the issue but its not showing up. Any ideas?

```js
$(function(){
            // global namespace
            var my = my || {};
            // models
            my.BabyWeight = function(pounds, ounces) {
                var self = this;

                self.pounds = pounds;
                self.remainingOunces = ounces;

                self.totalOunces = function() {
                    return (self.pounds * 16) + (self.remainingOunces * 1);
                };
                self.totalPounds = function() {
                    return (self.pounds * 1) + (self.remainingOunces / 16);
                };
                self.display = function() {
                    return self.pounds + 'lbs - ' + self.remainingOunces + 'oz';
                };
            };
            // view model
            my.vm = function(existingItems) {
                var self = this;

                // properties
                self.items = ko.observableArray(existingItems);
                self.msg = ko.observable("");
                self.msgType = ko.observable("info");
                self.title = ko.observable("Tracker v.001");

                // methods
                self.addItem = function() {
                    var pounds = $('#pounds').val();
                    var remainingOunces = $('#ounces').val();
                    var itemToAdd = new my.BabyWeight(pounds, remainingOunces);

                    // validate
                    if (itemToAdd.pounds == "" || itemToAdd.ounces == "") {
                        self.msgType("error");
                        self.msg("Oops, either the baby has become weightless or you didn't enter any data.");
                        return;
                    } else {
                        self.msg("");
                    }

                    // add to items array
                    self.items.push(itemToAdd);

                    // update msg
                    self.msgType("success");
                    self.msg("You've successfully weighed the baby in at " + itemToAdd.display());
                },
                self.clearItems = function() {

                    // clear items
                    self.items([]);

                    // update msg
                    self.msgType("info");
                    self.msg("All weight entries have been cleared.");
                },
                self.hideAlert = function() {
                    self.msg(""); //clearing the message will auto-hide since it's bound
                },
                self.removeItem = function(item) {

                    // remove item from items array
                    self.items.remove(item);

                    // update msg
                    self.msgType("info");
                    self.msg("The weight entry has been successfully removed.");
                }
            };

            // kick off knockout bindings
            ko.applyBindings(new my.vm([]));

            // add custom binding for charting
            ko.bindingHandlers.chart = {
                init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
                    // empty - left as placeholder if needed later
                },
                update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
                    // prepare chart values
                    var items = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor);
                    var chartValues = [
                        []
                    ];
                    for (var i = 0; i < items().length; i++) {
                        chartValues[0].push(items()[i].totalOunces());
                        console.log(totalOunces);
                    }

                    // clear previous chart
                    $(element).html("");

                    // plot chart
                    $.jqplot(element.id, chartValues, {
                        title: 'Baby Weight'
                    });
                }
            };

 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.8/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Add Baby Weight</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" data-bind="click: clearItems"><i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i> Start Over</button>
            </form>



            <!—-panel for my cute kids picture -->
            <div class="span4">

                <!-—we won’t cover adding this in the blog post -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span8">
            <div id="resultsChart" data-bind="chart: items()"></div>

            <table class="table table-striped" data-bind="visible: items().length > 0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Weight</td>
                        <td>Total Pounds</td>
                        <td>Total Ounces</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
                    <tr>
                        <td data-bind="text: display()"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: totalPounds()"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: totalOunces()"></td>
                        <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeItem"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The first obvious error: jqplot plugin should be attached _after_ jquery.

Comment: The binding handler needs to be defined before you apply bindings.

Comment: that doesnt seem to work